# Неисправность в питании ноутбука

Tags: ноутбук, hp

Ни с того ни с сего не включается ноутбук. При подключении к зарядке (исправна, проверял) индикатор не горит, впервые. Разобрал-собрал, толку ноль. Помогите, может мой косяк

[image: разъем для зарядки]

Comment: Попробуйте батарею вынуть. Возможно, без нее включится.

Comment: а что с батареей? от нее работает?

Comment: Не работает от родной батареи, а альтернативного АКБ нет. Без батареи от сети тоже не пашет (

Comment: Обратитесь в ближайшей сервисный центр. Вангование неисправности по фотографии - так себе идея.

Answer (score 0):

там целая масса причин может быть. я бы начал с того, что взял гарантировано исправную зарядку и подкинул ее (в зарядке может выйти из строя чип подтверждающий ноутбуку, что зарядка оригинальная), но это скорее всего не поможет и лучше сразу нести в проверенный ремонт

Comment: как высоко рекомендуете подкидывать? и стоит ли её ловить после этого?

Comment: ))
а если серьезно, то судя по фотке это старый HP, Вам будет дешевле с алика заказать материнку бэушную от него чем чинить эту, а еще

Comment: Лэптоп допотопный, тогда такие чипы не добавляли. А зарядка 100% рабочая, работаЕТ. Только вот ноут не видит ни ее, ни батарею - не светится индикатор и само сабой девайс не включился